# Kafka Producer throws error InterruptedException

Tags: apache-kafka, producer

During the initialization of kafka producer, an InterruptedException error appears. The problem is not regular, if you restart the application, then everything is fine. But periodically the application crashes because of this.

Error log:

```
 2023-04-12 10:52:24,307 INFO  [skExecutor-1] org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig     :  - ProducerConfig values: 
    acks = 1
    batch.size = 16384
    bootstrap.servers = [***p01*****:9093, ***p02*****:9093, ***p03*****:9093]
    buffer.memory = 33554432
    client.id = 
    compression.type = lz4
    connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
    enable.idempotence = false
    interceptor.classes = []
    key.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
    linger.ms = 0
    max.block.ms = 60000
    max.in.flight.requests.per.connection = 5
    max.request.size = 15728640
    metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
    metric.reporters = []
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    metrics.recording.level = INFO
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    partitioner.class = class org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.DefaultPartitioner
    receive.buffer.bytes = 32768
    reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
    reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
    request.timeout.ms = 30000
    retries = 50
    retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.jaas.config = null
    sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
    sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
    sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.login.class = null
    sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
    sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
    sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
    security.protocol = SSL
    send.buffer.bytes = 131072
    ssl.cipher.suites = [TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256]
    ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2]
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
    ssl.key.password = [hidden]
    ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
    ssl.keystore.location = /crm/cert/rto.keystore.jks
    ssl.keystore.password = [hidden]
    ssl.keystore.type = JKS
    ssl.protocol = SSL
    ssl.provider = null
    ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
    ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
    ssl.truststore.location = /crm/cert/truststore.jks
    ssl.truststore.password = [hidden]
    ssl.truststore.type = JKS
    transaction.timeout.ms = 60000
    transactional.id = null
    value.serializer = class org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer
 
2023-04-12 10:52:24,395 INFO  [skExecutor-1] o.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser$AppInfo :  - Kafka version : 2.0.0
 2023-04-12 10:52:24,396 INFO  [skExecutor-1] o.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser$AppInfo :  - Kafka commitId : 3402a8361b734732
 2023-04-12 10:52:24,857 ERROR [skExecutor-1] com.glow.gbp.mcp.crm.check.McpCheckTask      :  - General error java.lang.InterruptedException
 2023-04-12 10:52:24,860 ERROR [skExecutor-1] com.glow.gbp.mcp.crm.check.McpCheckTask      :  - Stacktrace:
 org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InterruptException: java.lang.InterruptedException
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.doSend(KafkaProducer.java:884)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.send(KafkaProducer.java:803)
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory$CloseSafeProducer.send(DefaultKafkaProducerFactory.java:285)
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.doSend(KafkaTemplate.java:357)
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.send(KafkaTemplate.java:188)
    at com.glowbyte.common.logging.writers.LogConsumer.accept(LogConsumer.java:24)
    at com.glow.common.logging.writers.LogConsumer.accept(LogConsumer.java:11)
    at com.glow.common.logging.writers.LogConsumer$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$483b29a6.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:746)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:88)
    at com.glow.common.logging.LogAspect.consumerLog(LogAspect.java:163)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:644)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:633)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:70)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:174)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
    at com.glow.common.logging.writers.LogConsumer$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c8375acb.accept(<generated>)
    at com.glow.common.logging.client.LogHttpRequestInterceptor.intercept(LogHttpRequestInterceptor.java:72)
    at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$InterceptingRequestExecution.execute(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:92)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.client.MetricsClientHttpRequestInterceptor.intercept(MetricsClientHttpRequestInterceptor.java:66)
    at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$InterceptingRequestExecution.execute(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:92)
    at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:76)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:723)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:680)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForEntity(RestTemplate.java:466)
    at com.glow.gbp.mcp.channel.McpEndpointImpl.check(McpEndpointImpl.java:47)
    at com.glow.gbp.mcp.crm.check.McpCheckTask.run(McpCheckTask.java:86)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
 Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException: null
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata.awaitUpdate(Metadata.java:181)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.waitOnMetadata(KafkaProducer.java:938)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.doSend(KafkaProducer.java:823)
    ... 39 common frames omitted
```

No errors were found on the broker's side and in /var/log/messages.